# TypeError: unbound method __init__() during practicing TDD example by Python from TDDBE

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

I am now practicing TDD by python using Test Driven Development by Example written by Kent Beck. Follwing the example, I composed the code which is same with the example in TDDBE.

```
class TestCase:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        exec "self." + self.name + "()"

class WasRun:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.wasRun = None
        TestCase.__init__(self, name)

    def testMethod(self):
        self.wasRun = 1

test = WasRun("testMethod")
print test.wasRun
test.run()
print test.wasRun
```

But when I run this code, I found that the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sanghee/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    test = WasRun("testMethod")
  File "/Users/sanghee/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 11, in __init__
    TestCase.__init__(self, name)
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with TestCase instance as first argument (got WasRun instance instead)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can you let me know what is the problem? And why?

Comment: Why are you practicing TDD without using the `unittest` module? It already provide `TestCase`, `TestSuite` classes with all the `assert`, `setUp`, `tearDown` etc methods. You are reinventing the wheel...

Comment: Hi Bakuriu, I just follow the example in TDDBE. Thank you for your opinion. I will try that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `WasRun` class a subclass of `TestCase`:

```
class WasRun(TestCase):
```

Now `self` is an instance of (a subclass of) `TestCase`.

Note that the code you quote is not exactly best practice; I'd rewrite it to at least use new-style classes, use `super()` to call the superclass initializer, and to avoid `exec` statements:

```
class TestCase(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        getattr(self, self.name)()

class WasRun(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.wasRun = False
        super(WasRun, self).__init__(name)

    def testMethod(self):
        self.wasRun = True
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn Pieters. I totally understand what you said. Especially getatter instead of exec is nice to me and more intuitive. Thanks.